# How to serve two angular apps on same node express server with different path level

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I succeed to serve two different angular apps (the shop for cutomers and the admin part for company staff) on the same node server at the same level path with:

```
// Serves admin app
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../admin")))
app.get("/admin*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../admin/index.html"))})

// Serves customers app
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname," ../shop")))
app.get("/shop*", (req, res) => { 
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../shop/index.html"))})
```

This works very well  and I can access my two apps with the two different urls:

```
www.my-company.com/shop
www.my-company.com/admin
```

But I would like the customers to access the shop directly with `www.my-company.com` without "/shop" at the end, so I changed the node app.js as below:

```
// Serves admin app
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../admin"))) // unchanged
app.get("/admin*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../admin/index.html"))})

// Serves customers app
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname," ../shop"))) //unchanged
app.get("/*", (req, res) => { 
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../shop/index.html"))})
```

And on the angular side, I configured the index.html for admin with `<base href="/admin">` and the index.html for the shop app with `<base href="/">`.

Then, when I can call `www.my-company.com/admin` or any path starting by "admin" I access the admin app as expected, but when I call root url `www.my-company.com` I am also redirected to the admin app!
The paths that redirect me to the shop app are all routes not managed in the node express server BUT root url, for example `www.company.com/url-not-exist` will redirects me to the customer app.

How should I configure my nodejs express and app distributions so I can have my two different apps from `www.my-company.com` and `www.my-company.com/admin`?

I run node.js v14.15.1 with express 4.17.1, and my two angular apps are on v12.

Answer (score 0):

When you define app.use you can define the route as well.

```
app.use('/admin', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname," ../admin")));
// all routes starts with /admin
// don't forget to have a base url in your admin portal, all links should have correct links which starts with /admin

app.use('*', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname," ../shop")));
// all routes except /admin
```

Instead of adding this complexity you can start to use subdomains.

[www.admin.my-company.com](http://www.admin.my-company.com) -> Links to admin node.js server

[www.my-company.com](http://www.my-company.com) -> Links to main node.js server

Comment: When I define the route on app.use I have a strange behavior: this time the urls are called as expected but I receive only blank pages! I can see the good app is sent in the debug network tab of my browser because I can see all files from the good app (main, pollyfills runtime and styles) but I have a blank htmll page instead of the app... Thanks for the subdomains solution, I'll have a look too

Comment: Are you sure those builds/folders have index.html?

Comment: Yes they have, I can access the two apps if I do it on the same path level, i.e. www.my-company.com/shop and www.my-company.com/admin instead of www.my-company.com and www.my-company.com/admin

Comment: What if you replace '*' with '/' in the second use command?